# how to save a video in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

hi can any one describe me sample code for
how to save a video using save button in cocoa.
i have stop and start button. i need one save button to save the video.

Answer (score 1):

You will need this one....
http://servin.com/iphone/iPhone-File-IO.html

and also this code will save your video...

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:yourfilePath contents:yourVideo attributes:nil];
```